# How do I give priority to the user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, priority-queue

I have User database table with `status (Int field)`, `timestamp` and `priority_flag (Int field)` fields. I am using the following query to prioritize the user.

```
users = User.objects.filter(status=status).order_by('priority_flag', 'timestamp')
```

If the user has high priority_flag, that user should first respond to the query. For example, there are 2 users.

`Bob = [priority_flag=Standard, timestamp=datetime.datetime(2007, 2, 17, 23, 42, 31, 584349, tzinfo=<UTC>)]`

`Alice = [priority_flag=Emergency, timestamp=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 17, 23, 42, 31, 584349, tzinfo=<UTC>)]`

Even if the user Alice is created 10 years later, but her priority is higher than Bob. It should response first. 
What am I doing wrong here ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort by `priority_flag` in descending order, use `'-priority_flag'`.

```
users = User.objects.filter(status=status).order_by('-priority_flag', 'timestamp')
```